# how to create a jms connection factory using command line admin tools?

Tags: glassfish, jms, openmq

I'm using openmq with glassfish and i currently use the gf web admin tool to create connection factories and destinations. i've found commands to create destinations using the imqcmd utility however have had no luck creating connection factories. can anybody point me in the correct direction to creating a Queue connection factory using the openmq command line tools?

For reference here is what i'm using to create the destination

imqcmd create dst -t q -n MyFavoriteQueue -u admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [imqobjmgr](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19148-01/819-4467/gbnlk/index.html) utility.

imqobjmgr add
   -l "cn=myQCF"
   -j "java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
   -j "java.naming.provider.url=ldap://mydomain.com:389/o=imq"
   -j "java.naming.security.principal=uid=homerSimpson,ou=People,o=imq"
   -j "java.naming.security.credentials=doh"
   -j "java.naming.security.authentication=simple"
   -t qf
   -o "imqAddressList=mq://myHost:7272/jms"